# How to make a uicollectionview that can add new cells on click of a button and has adjustable heights for each cell and the heights stay persistent

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a stacking uicollectionview that has the ability to have it's height adjusted based on the value of a slider. The problem I am running into is that the heights of the cells have a default value of 100:

[gif of action I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhNlh.gif)

I do not want the default height stuck at 100, I want the default height of the cell to be the height that the slider was at before I clicked the next button.

code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sliderSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionThing: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var buttonButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonButton1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonButton2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonButton3: UIButton!


var visualArray = [String]()
var heightArray = [CGSize]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionThing.dataSource = self


    collectionThing.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: (-(CGFloat)(Double.pi)))

}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return visualArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.row == visualArray.count - 1  {
        let theHeight = CGSize(width: 200, height: Int(sliderSlider.value * 10))
        heightArray.append(theHeight)
        print(heightArray)
        return theHeight
    }
    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VisualCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! VisualCollectionViewCell

    cell.visualLabel.text = visualArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)


    if visualArray.last == "Zero" {
        if indexPath.row == visualArray.count - 1 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .green
        }
    }
    if visualArray.last == "One" {
        if indexPath.row == visualArray.count - 1 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue

        }
    }

    if visualArray.last == "Two" {
        if indexPath.row == visualArray.count - 1 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }

    if visualArray.last == "Three" {
        if indexPath.row == visualArray.count - 1 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .orange
        }
    }

    return cell
}


@IBAction func sliderActionValue(_ sender: Any) {
    collectionThing.reloadData()
}



@IBAction func buttonButton0Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    visualArray.append("Zero")
    collectionThing.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func butttonButton1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    visualArray.append("One")
    collectionThing.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func buttonButton2Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    visualArray.append("Two")
    collectionThing.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func buttonButton3Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    visualArray.append("Three")
    collectionThing.reloadData()
}
```

I believe that where the issue lies is in the return value of the heights of the cell. However, I am not sure how to make the height persistent based on the value of the uislider.

The next issue I am having is that the colors seem to get jumbled: 
[gif of color problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92TV7.gif)

Unfortunately, I have no idea why this is happening. Any insight into any of these problems are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don’t rely on slider view calculating `sizeForItemAt`. Store heights separately and update them when slider moves. Then use that data.

Comment: Thank you, but can you elaborate a little bit more? I am not quite understanding what you mean by store heights separately. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, disregard that comment, I misunderstood your code. Currently all your cells are 200x100 except for the last one. Is it what you want? If no you should probably use your heightArray instead of returning that constant. Also beware adding several items to heightArray when you need only one.